# R: add a column according to values in two tables

Tags: r

I have Table1 and Table2 and I want to get Table3.

For each row in Table3

- id has to be in both Table1 and Table2
- the value of var = the value of var in Table 2
- one column var_difference is added where var_difference = Table2.var - Table1.var

Table1:

```
id var
01 2
02 3
```

Table2:

```
id var
02 4
03 5
```

Table3:

```
id var var_difference
02 4   1
```

Comment: in this example, 02 is the only id that is in common and Table1.var =3, Table2.var = 4, so var_difference = 4-3 =1

Comment: Go through this, and eventually you'll see a slide on "merging data": http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/seminars/intro.htm

Answer (score 4):

**Data**

```
t1 <- data.frame(id = paste0("0", 1:2), var = 2:3)
t2 <- data.frame(id = paste0("0", 2:3), var = 4:5)
```

**Code**

```
transform(merge(t1, t2, by = "id"), 
          var = var.x, var_difference = var.y - var.x,
          var.x = NULL, var.y = NULL)
#   id var var_difference
# 1 02   3              1
```

**Explanation**

With `merge` you create a `data.frame` which contains the rows which have the same `id`. `transform` works on the returned `data.frame` and formats the output you wanted to have. SO first, the column `var` is created then the column `var_difference`. Finally, `var.x` and `var.y` are deleted. The latter columns were created by `merge` and represent the `var` columns of the two arguments of `merge` (`t1`and `t2`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For me that makes the difference between an answer and a great answer as that does indeed theach someone how to fish.

Answer (score 0):

```
tab3 <- merge(tab1, tab2, by = "id")
tab3$var_difference <- tab3[ ,3] - tab3[ ,2]
tab3 <- tab3[ ,-2:-3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempt the following:

```
Table3 <- merge(Table1[,'id'], Table2, by.x = 'id', by.y = 'id')
Table3$var_difference <- Table2$var[Table2$id %in% Table3$id] - Table1$var[Table1$id %in% Table3$id]
```

Comment: I think you may want a `drop=FALSE` since `Table1[,'id']` evaluates to a vector with no name (thanks to an R oddity). Try `data.frame(a=1:3)[,'a']` versus `data.frame(a=1:3)[,'a',drop=FALSE]`

Comment: Thanks Frank. I'll do that.